Quantum Phase Estimation for Chemical Hamiltonian
I am working on implementing QPE for calculating the ground state energy of a small molecule like H2 or HeH+. I've written some code that is getting results within about 10% accuracy, but I'm not entirely sure it is correct or why the accuracy is not better. Here is the code:
def get_qubit_op(dist):
    molecule = MoleculeInfo(
        symbols=["H", "H"],
        coords=([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [dist, 0.0, 0.0]),
        multiplicity = 1,
        charge = 0,
    )

    driver = PySCFDriver.from_molecule(molecule)
    problem = driver.run()

    num_particles = problem.num_particles
    num_spatial_orbitals = problem.num_spatial_orbitals
    mapper = ParityMapper(num_particles=num_particles)
    qubit_op = mapper.map(problem.second_q_ops()[0])
    
    return qubit_op, num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals, problem, mapper

def exact_solver(qubit_op, problem):
    sol = NumPyMinimumEigensolver().compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
    result = problem.interpret(sol)
    return result

for dist in np.arange(0.5, 1.7, 0.1):
    (qubit_op, num_particles, num_spatial_orbitals, problem, mapper) = get_qubit_op(dist)
    
    # Calculate exact eigenvalues with NumPyEigensolver for reference
    result = exact_solver(qubit_op, problem)
    exact_energy = result.total_energies[0].real
    #print(f"Exact ground state energy: {exact_energy - problem.nuclear_repulsion_energy} Hartree")
    
    num_qubits = qubit_op.num_qubits
    
    # Set up the QPE circuit
    n_ancillas = 12  # Number of ancilla qubits for phase estimation
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_ancillas + num_qubits, n_ancillas)
    qc.x(n_ancillas) # For Hartree-Fock initial state
    qc.h(range(n_ancillas))
    
    # Apply the controlled unitary operations
    for i in range(n_ancillas):
        evolution_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(qubit_op, time = 2 ** i)
        qc.append(evolution_gate.control(), [i] + list(range(n_ancillas, n_ancillas + num_qubits)))
    
    qc.append(QFT(n_ancillas, inverse=True), range(n_ancillas))
    qc.measure(range(n_ancillas), range(n_ancillas))

    # Execute the circuit
    sampler = StatevectorSampler()
    shots = 10000
    job_sampler = sampler.run([qc], shots=shots)
    result_sampler = job_sampler.result()
    counts = result_sampler[0].data.c.get_counts()
    
    # Assuming counts is a dictionary with bitstrings as keys and counts as values
    energies = []
    probabilities = []
    total_counts = sum(counts.values())
    
    for bitstring, count in counts.items():
        phase = int(bitstring, 2) / 2 ** n_ancillas
        evolution_time = 1
        energy = -1 * (phase * (2 * np.pi) / evolution_time)
        probabilities.append(count / total_counts)
        energies.append(energy)
    
    # Calculate expected value of energy
    expected_energy = sum(p * e for p, e in zip(probabilities, energies))
    
    #print("Expected ground state energy: ", expected_energy)
    print(f"Distance: {round(dist,2)} | Exact Energy: {round(exact_energy - problem.nuclear_repulsion_energy,14)} | QPE Energy: {round(expected_energy,14)} | Error: {round((expected_energy - (exact_energy - problem.nuclear_repulsion_energy))/expected_energy*100,2)}")

You can use these installs and imports, maybe in a venv or google colab:
# %pip install qiskit[visualization]==1.0.2
# %pip install qiskit_aer
# %pip install qiskit_ibm_runtime
# %pip install qiskit_algorithms
# %pip install qiskit_nature
# %pip install matplotlib
# %pip install pylatexenc
# %pip install pyscf

import numpy as np
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT
from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli
from qiskit_algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit_algorithms import NumPyEigensolver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.drivers import PySCFDriver
from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import ParityMapper
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT, PauliEvolutionGate
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector, Operator, SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.primitives import StatevectorSampler, PrimitiveJob
from qiskit_nature.second_q.formats.molecule_info import MoleculeInfo
from qiskit_nature.second_q.transformers import FreezeCoreTransformer
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

A few things I'm unsure of:

This differs quite a bit from the approach given by Classiq here (https://github.com/Classiq/classiq-library/blob/main/applications/chemistry/qpe_for_molecules/qpe_for_molecules.ipynb) in that I am not normalizing the matrix beforehand, and I am calculating the final energy from the phases differently (by summing the product of the probabilities and estimated energies). While it seems better to not normalize beforehand in one sense - you don't necessarily need to calculate the eigenvalues on a classical computer before doing it redundantly on the quantum computer - I'm not sure why this method is working compared to theirs.

The values I am getting are still somewhat far from the correct value. Below are the energies I obtained by running the above code. In some cases the error is high, such as 7.5%. Changing the number of ancillary qubits or shots does not seem to improve this.


Distance: 0.5 | Exact Energy: -2.11351421631063 | QPE Energy: -2.14500905415295 | Error: 1.47
Distance: 0.6 | Exact Energy: -1.99824802506954 | QPE Energy: -2.08107319510811 | Error: 3.98
Distance: 0.7 | Exact Energy: -1.89215689823735 | QPE Energy: -1.96451734649451 | Error: 3.68
Distance: 0.8 | Exact Energy: -1.7956191803271  | QPE Energy: -1.79854492039149 | Error: 0.16
Distance: 0.9 | Exact Energy: -1.70853496009999 | QPE Energy: -1.81276538248943 | Error: 5.75
Distance: 1.0 | Exact Energy: -1.63032754115262 | QPE Energy: -1.73071413072813 | Error: 5.8
Distance: 1.1 | Exact Energy: -1.56026313671453 | QPE Energy: -1.61435002971302 | Error: 3.35
Distance: 1.2 | Exact Energy: -1.49772175540526 | QPE Energy: -1.54652737014784 | Error: 3.16
Distance: 1.3 | Exact Energy: -1.44224565944964 | QPE Energy: -1.50579143653899 | Error: 4.22
Distance: 1.4 | Exact Energy: -1.39345197137396 | QPE Energy: -1.49800663743854 | Error: 6.98
Distance: 1.5 | Exact Energy: -1.35093416075141 | QPE Energy: -1.46044481687598 | Error: 7.5
Distance: 1.6 | Exact Energy: -1.31420848585817 | QPE Energy: -1.4036941238416  | Error: 6.38

I appreciate the help fixing this algorithm implementation.
